# Use Skrollr in a div other than body

Tags: javascript, html, css, skrollr

How do I use Skrollr on a page if I already use a different div to scroll (#scrollable) other than the body?

For example, I have this:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#scrollable {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I want to have a "skroller area" inside a page when it reaches a certain div.

I'm trying with this:

```
  var s = skrollr.init({
    skrollrBody: '#scrollable'
  });
```

But it doesn't seem to work, I scroll and I don't see the styles update in DevTools.

Comment: hi zok can you tell me have solved this issue. i need your help how to achieve skrollr on specific div rather than body